# How to set post_per_page on custom post Categories page template?

Tags: wordpress, post

I have created a custom template for a post Category page containing custom post fields. It's an "Events" page, where I am hiding past posts (event_date_end). The issue now is that 'post_per_page' is not working. I think it's somewhat inhering from the theme, which is up to 8 posts. I want to display all posts (except for past events).

```
/*
Events Category Template
*/

// get posts
$posts = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'          => "event_date_end",
    'meta_compare'      => '>=',  
    'meta_value'        => date("Ymd"),
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
 );

$posts=get_posts($posts);

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="cat-title"><?php echo single_cat_title(); ?></h1>
        <div id="content-area" class="clearfix">
            <div id="left-area">
            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            ?>
                    <!-- Divi Library for Events-->
                    <?php echo do_shortcode('[et_pb_section global_module="2564"][/et_pb_section]');?> 
            <?php
                    endwhile;

                    if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) )
                        wp_pagenavi();
            //      else
            //          get_template_part( 'includes/navigation', 'index' );
            //  else :
            //      get_template_part( 'includes/no-results', 'index' );
                endif;
            ?>
            </div> <!-- #left-area -->

            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        </div> <!-- #content-area -->
    </div> <!-- .container -->
</div> <!-- #main-content -->

<?php

get_footer();
```

I also have tried adding the code below to functions.php , which worked but it's not hiding past events (its actually adding empty entries to the bottom):

```
// Increase limit of posts on Events/Agenda pages
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_in_category');

function posts_in_category($query){
    if ($query->is_category) {
        if (is_category('agenda')) {
            $query->set('posts_per_archive_page', -1);
        }

        if (is_category('agenda-fr')){
            $query->set('posts_per_archive_page', -1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you setting the post loop on your page to actually use the `get_posts()` query result? For example `if($posts->have_posts(): foreach ($posts as $post):setup_postdata( $post ); ) ...do your stuff here...endforeach;endif;`

Comment: @Azer Yes. I just updated my question with the whole code

Comment: @Azer What I have there is correct? like `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not telling your post loop to use the fetched posts, but instead they are using the global posts that was originally fetched by your theme.

Try this small fix:

```
if ( count($posts) > 0 ) : foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
// Your code here
endforeach; endif;
```

This way you are setting up the loop to use the posts from the `get_posts()` query.

After your loop is finished, you can reset the global post data to use the original post query again with `wp_reset_postdata();` In general, it's good practice to add this after a custom loop is finished.

Comment: Do you mean replace `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();` with your code? That didn't work...

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. At least then you can be sure it's using the correct query results. Which means that the query itself does not give you the result you had hoped for. By the way, what does that short code do in your loop? `[et_pb_section global_module="2564"][/et_pb_section]`

Comment: @Marcio Hey, I updated my answer. I'm sorry, I realized I was telling you to do something that's not possible. Only the `WP_Query` object has the `have_posts()` and `the_post()` methods. `get_posts()` just returns an array of post objects instead. Please try the edited code instead! Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately that didn't work either. That repeated the last post several times instead of showing all the posts.

Comment: @Marcio Hmm, sounds like the issue might be with the code you are putting in the loop. In your code above, you only run a shortcode inside the loop. Could you tell me what this shortcode is supposed to do? And what `global_module="2564"` is supposed to refer to? Basically, if you run the exact same code for every post in the query, then your result would be the same thing over and over again. Which I think is what might be happening here.

Comment: the loop works how I have it, the only problem is the 'post_per_page'. The shortcode is a layout using Divi theme. It's pretty much a section with divs containing thing like: post title, image, description, data, etc...

Comment: @Marcio I see. Then my guess would be that there is some other plugin or theme function that's interfering. Try opening the ´wp-content´  folder in your IDE and search the whole catalogue for `'posts_per_page'`. If some other plugin or theme function is changing the query settings there's a chance you might find it.